# UIPickerView Dinamico en array de metadatos desde backend || Crear UIPICKERSVIEWS dinamico

Tags: swift, xcode

Mi objetivo es dibujar controles dinamicamente desde un array de metadatos que viene desde el backend por ejemplo este

```
"MetadataServicio": [
    {
      "DATA_TYPE": "Varchar", 
      "ERROR_DESC": "", 
      "FIELD_LENGTH": "25", 
      "FIELD_TYPE": "Textbox", 
      "FK_ID_SERVICIO": "009", 
      "IS_QUERY": "0", 
      "LABEL": "Dato", 
      "ORDEN": "2", 
      "VALIDATION": "null", 
      "VALUE": ""
    }, 
    {
      "DATA_TYPE": "", 
      "ERROR_DESC": "", 
      "FIELD_LENGTH": "", 
      "FIELD_TYPE": "Combo", 
      "FK_ID_SERVICIO": "009", 
      "IS_QUERY": "0", 
      "LABEL": "Identificador", 
      "ORDEN": "1", 
      "VALIDATION": "", 
      "VALUE": "[{\"Valor\":\"C\u00e9dula\"},{\"Valor\":\"Cuenta\"}]"
    }
  ]
```

Esto de aqui significa que tenga un combo que tendra 2 valores Cedula y Cuenta, pero podrian ser n combos que tuviera que crear dinamicamente

Para esto cree una clase que contiene

```
class ArrayComboBoxDatas {
    var selectedObject : String
    var pickerObject   : UIPickerView
    var destinationEntities : [String]
    var orden : String
    var textField:TextField
}
```

Y en mi clase donde agrego los controles tengo un array de dicha clase

```
var arrayCombosBoxsOn = [ArrayComboBoxDatas]()
```

Luego para agregar los combo realizo :

```
 func agregarComboBox(metaDato:ServiceMetaData){

    var txtAux = TextField.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21))
    txtAux.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    txtAux.textColor = UIColor.black
    txtAux.tag = Int(metaDato.ORDEN)!

    var comboBoxOnAux = ArrayComboBoxDatas.init()

    comboBoxOnAux.selectedObject = ""
    let pickewViewAux = UIPickerView()
    pickewViewAux.tag = Int(metaDato.ORDEN)!
    comboBoxOnAux.pickerObject = pickewViewAux
    comboBoxOnAux.orden = metaDato.ORDEN

    var arrayStringStringAux = [String]()

    let keysValues = metaDato.VALUE
    let data = keysValues.data(using: .utf8)!

    do {
        if let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options : .allowFragments) as? [Dictionary<String,Any>]
        {
            for valores in jsonArray {
                var valor = valores["Valor"] as! String
                arrayStringStringAux.append(valor)
            }

        } else {
            print("bad json")
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }

    comboBoxOnAux.destinationEntities = arrayStringStringAux

    self.arrayCombosBoxsOn.append(comboBoxOnAux)



}
```

Esto lo que hace es llenar mi Array de combos el cual contiene referencia a la caja creada al picker de el y sus datos, para luego recorrer todo este array y crear las coneciones de los pickers

> func crearPickers(){

```
    for info  in arrayCombosBoxsOn{


        let toolbar = UIToolbar()
        toolbar.sizeToFit()
        let done = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: #selector(donePressedGeneric))
        toolbar.setItems([done], animated: false)

        info.textField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
        info.textField.inputView = info.pickerObject
        info.pickerObject.delegate = self
        info.pickerObject.dataSource = self
        info.pickerObject.tag = 4

        self.viewStack.addArrangedSubview(info.textField)
    }
}
```

El tema viene el los delegate

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        switch pickerView.tag {
        case 0:
            return CommonViewController.OrigenesCuentas.count
        case 1:
            return servicesTypesArray.count
        case 2:
            return servicesArray.count
        default:


        }
```

Como yo podria en base a lo que tengo dinamicamente colocar la cantidad y demas datos?? como podria resolver el mostrar combos dinamicamente mas sencillo que un uipickersview? , estoy abierto a lograrse asi de la forma en lo que pense o buscar alternativas mas eficientes gracias

Comment: Lo que no veo es no tienes un customPicker por defecto, se me ocurre que se puede crear un customPicker, de esta manera crear propiedades por defecto la cual van hacer cambiada al momento de consumir el servicio del backend. de esta manera mostraras el picker del servicio y no hay un fallo del lado del backend tiene uno por defecto.

Comment: Me dices que no tengo un uipickerview por defecto? , es que justamente necesito que todo se haga dinamico, creo que entendiste mi pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta muy interesante tu planteamiento, yo lo resolvería de esta forma: 
Ademas de tener un arreglo de combos **self.arrayCombosBoxsOn** Tendría otro arreglo o diccionario de valores, sería algo como esto:

```
var arayValores: [Int:[String:String]]
```

Este lo vas llenando tu función agregarComboBox  con el tag que le estas asignando al picker como llave del diccionario y el arreglo de valores como valor

Entonces el delegate te quedaría algo como esto:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return arayValores[pickerView.tag].count 
        }
```

El delegate de los títulos o celdas seria un poco mas complicado porque tendrías que ordenar el diccionario de valores para que quede como arreglo.

Espero funcione.

Comment: hace 3 semanas tengo esta pregunta abierta con recompensas, Primero que nada gracias por tomarte un tiempo de leer y ayudarme a pensar este problema, voy a probar lo que me dices me re gusta como suena y me parece puede venir perfecto, lo probare en unas horas cuando pueda tocar ete proyecto, por ahora te dejo las gracias y un abrazo grande

Comment: Muy bien, espero te funcione, si no con gusto lo resolvemos búscame y lo resolvemos mas en corto, me gustan mucho este tipo de problemas.  Abrazo

Comment: la verdad no puedo implementar tu ayuda @hugo como agrego los valores a este tipo de datos??  [Int:[String:String]] , perdona soy bastante nobato

Comment: Intento hacerlo y subo le código.

Comment: Listo estimado, luego de darle varias vueltas pude hacer que completara el combo, me encuentro con grandes problemas para poder hacer el action del boton Done dinamicamente pero ya es para otra pregunta